# Select colums in an indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported a csv file with pd.read_csv, used parse_dates and index_col.
This results in de following dataframe

```
DatetimeIndex: 195972 entries, 2018-02-01 to 2019-10-25
Data columns (total 19 columns):
account_manager    195972 non-null object
article_des        195896 non-null object
article_n          195972 non-null object
article_o          195972 non-null object
budget_code        195972 non-null object
budget_naam        195972 non-null object
country            195972 non-null object
currency           195972 non-null object
customer           195972 non-null object
industrie          195972 non-null object
klantnaam          195972 non-null object
month              195972 non-null int64
revenue            195972 non-null float64
revenue_local      195972 non-null float64
sap_code           195972 non-null object
volume             195972 non-null float64
week               195972 non-null int64
weight             195972 non-null float64
year               195972 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(3), object(12)
memory usage: 20.9+ MB
None
```

I've tried every possible way to select only one column (weight) from this dataframe in a new dataframe. None of them work. What;s the trick to select columns in an indexed dataframe?
If I import the csv without an index_col I can make any selection I want.

Comment: Using df[['weight']] doesn't work ?

Comment: You are probably dealing with whitespace.  `df.to_dict()` to check and see.  Then do `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` to fix.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

`df['weight']` will return a series while `df[['weight']]` will return a DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'])

print(df)
#    a  b
# 0  1  2
# 1  3  4
print(type(df['a']))
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
print(type(df[['a']]))
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

To select multiple columns, you have to pass a list of column names.

```
print(df[['a', 'b']])
#    a  b
# 0  1  2
# 1  3  4
```

So to select a single column as a DataFrame, pass a list of one element.

```
print(df[['a']])
#    a
# 0  1
# 1  3
```